# SPF, DKIM, DMARC, DomainKeys OK, emails flagged as SPAM

Tags: postfix, centos7, dkim, domainkeys, dmarc

I have a new dedicated server running CentOS7 with Plesk 12.5 with postfix, and i have succesfully set SPF, DKIM, DMARC and DomainKeys as it shows this test from port25.com:

==========================================================

## Summary of Results

SPF check: pass
DomainKeys check: pass
DKIM check: pass
Sender-ID check: pass
SpamAssassin check: ham

==========================================================

## Details:

HELO hostname: s17772156.onlinehome-server.info
Source IP: 217.160.108.200
mail-from: hola@pixeldraw.net

---

### SPF check details:

Result: pass
ID(s) verified: smtp.mailfrom=hola@pixeldraw.net
DNS record(s):
pixeldraw.net. SPF (no records)
pixeldraw.net. 146 IN TXT "v=spf1 +a +mx +a:s17772156.onlinehome-server.info +ip4:217.160.108.200 ?all"
pixeldraw.net. 146 IN A 104.27.131.21
pixeldraw.net. 146 IN A 104.27.130.21
pixeldraw.net. 146 IN MX 10 dc-7e1939e7-mail.pixeldraw.net.
pixeldraw.net. 146 IN MX 15 dc-7e1939e7-mail2.pixeldraw.net.
dc-7e1939e7-mail.pixeldraw.net. 146 IN A 217.160.108.200

---

### DomainKeys check details:

Result: pass
ID(s) verified: header.From=hola@pixeldraw.net
DNS record(s):
default._domainkey.pixeldraw.net. 300 IN TXT "p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDo4L1i8d6w2Ha/0WQeYZGO4AiRsklou5TmD5evr/qm30I+sShcNIFV1/Iwp5pQ+u1Sb3fdvygjnX/M64E10phErjKuTkdytZQMK8iG4umB21V9qodSbqhAjvpKWE1XVS3aQNOtX83AynGSvJqSfPwetea7JOCkrnmrl/JZtq+Z1wIDAQAB;"

---

### DKIM check details:

Result: pass (matches From: hola@pixeldraw.net)
ID(s) verified: header.d=pixeldraw.net
Canonicalized Headers:
date:Sat,'20'28'20'Nov'20'2015'20'09:40:52'20'+0100'0D''0A'
from:pixel'20'draw'20'solutions'20''0D''0A'
to:check-auth@verifier.port25.com'0D''0A'
subject:=?UTF-8?Q?Presupuesto_dise=C3=B1o_web?='0D''0A'
dkim-signature:v=1;'20'a=rsa-sha256;'20'c=relaxed/simple;'20'd=pixeldraw.net;'20's=mail;'20't=1448700052;'20'bh=Ri2xCyysAfo3Wyf+vvBIZr/qPlV0rS9rO2/aGNmpjWI=;'20'h=Date:From:To:Subject;'20'b=

Canonicalized Body:
Hola'20'Christian,'0D''0A'
'0D''0A'
'0D''0A'
'0D''0A'
Una'20'web'20'sencilla'20'de'20'presentaci'C3''B3'n'20'te'20'costar'C3''AD'a'20'220'20'euros'20'+'20'IVA'20'con'20'hasta'20'5'20''0D''0A'
secciones,'20'una'20'galer'C3''AD'a'20'foto,'20'un'20'formulario'20'de'20'contacto,'20'con'20'dise'C3''B1'o'20''0D''0A'
gr'C3''A1'fico'20'incluido'20'como'20'banners/ofertas,'20'mapa'20'google,'20'dominio'20'y'20''0D''0A'
alojamiento,'20'tutorial'20'administrativo,'20'c'C3''B3'pias'20'de'20'seguridad.'0D''0A'
'0D''0A'
'0D''0A'
A'20'esta'20'web'20'si'20'le'20'quieres'20'a'C3''B1'adir'20'una'20'tienda'20'te'20'costar'C3''AD'a'20'60'20'euros'20''0D''0A'
adicionales'20'con'20'hasta'20'20'20'productos'20'introducidos'20'por'20'nosotros'20'(sin'20'l'C3''AD'mite'20''0D''0A'
de'20'productos).'0D''0A'
'0D''0A'
Quedo'20'a'20'tu'20'disposici'C3''B3'n'20'para'20'cualquier'20'consulta,'0D''0A'
'0D''0A'
'0D''0A'
---'0D''0A'
pixel'20'draw'20'solutions'0D''0A'
+34'20'622572818'20'-'20'www.pixeldraw.net'0D''0A'

DNS record(s):
mail._domainkey.pixeldraw.net. 300 IN TXT "v=DKIM1;k=rsa;p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC+Lim9Q4c5hyrbwnohpdU4LIVc8Y4skHESPq6fjhJEKT4Pq85nxt3GXLMbXZMyBLtYJVZSwyoIm+XmiotNwqv66t35skC4QCWrMEK8x9K4VZZK8tW/BVg5zOh4W4xH1Dlp52pidkC4JZzhJAjP0VSMW3/H3HlhCQoUoxleb/zKPQIDAQAB;"

Public key used for verification: mail._domainkey.pixeldraw.net (1024 bits)

NOTE: DKIM checking has been performed based on the latest DKIM specs
(RFC 4871 or draft-ietf-dkim-base-10) and verification may fail for
older versions. If you are using Port25's PowerMTA, you need to use
version 3.2r11 or later to get a compatible version of DKIM.

---

### Sender-ID check details:

Result: pass
ID(s) verified: header.From=hola@pixeldraw.net
DNS record(s):
pixeldraw.net. SPF (no records)
pixeldraw.net. 146 IN TXT "v=spf1 +a +mx +a:s17772156.onlinehome-server.info +ip4:217.160.108.200 ?all"
pixeldraw.net. 146 IN A 104.27.131.21
pixeldraw.net. 146 IN A 104.27.130.21
pixeldraw.net. 146 IN MX 10 dc-7e1939e7-mail.pixeldraw.net.
pixeldraw.net. 146 IN MX 15 dc-7e1939e7-mail2.pixeldraw.net.
dc-7e1939e7-mail.pixeldraw.net. 146 IN A 217.160.108.200

---

### SpamAssassin check details:

SpamAssassin v3.4.0 (2014-02-07)

Result: ham (-2.0 points, 5.0 required)

pts rule name description

---

0.0 URIBL_BLOCKED ADMINISTRATOR NOTICE: The query to URIBL was blocked.
See
http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/DnsBlocklists#dnsbl-block
for more information.
[URIs: pixeldraw.net]
-0.0 SPF_PASS SPF: sender matches SPF record
-1.9 BAYES_00 BODY: Bayes spam probability is 0 to 1%
[score: 0.0000]
-0.1 DKIM_VALID_AU Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from author's
domain
0.1 DKIM_SIGNED Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily valid
-0.1 DKIM_VALID Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature

Answer (score 1):

Use the free DNS report at http://www.dnsstuff.com/ to detect issues with your DNS as a possible culprit.

Then once you receive no errors or warnings on your DNS report, you can proceed to sending mail to the generated email at https://www.mail-tester.com

If you pass all of those and still have issues, register with dmarcian.com and use the diagnostic and inspector tools to determine the problem.

Just at first glance your domain does not have an MX record and your SOA record is out of whack.